# Error: You have an error in your SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''violation','officer','date','time') values('2101093','100','2','Daryl','Coronad' at line 1

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("dbposo",$conn);

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $number=$_POST['id'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $violation=$_POST['violation'];
    $officer=$_POST['officer'];
    $date=date("y-m-d");
    $time=date("H:i:s");

    $violation=mysql_query("select count(number) as offensecount from tblcitizen where number='$number'",$conn);
    if($data=mysql_fetch_array($violation))
    {
        $offensecount=$data['offensecount'];

        if($offensecount==1)
        {
            mysql_query("insert into tblcitizen(number, price, offenses, fname, lname, age, gender,'violation','officer','date','time') values('$number','100','2','$fname','$lname','$age','$gender','$violation','$officer','$date','$time')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<script>alert('2nd Offense: 300php Penalty!');</script>";
            header('Refresh: 0; URL=admin_publicviolation.php');
        }
        else if($offensecount==2)
        {
            mysql_query("insert into tblcitizen(number, price, offenses, fname, lname,'age','gender','violation','officer','date','time') values('$number','500','3','$fname','$lname','$age','$gender','$violation','$officer','$date','$time')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<script>alert('3rd Offense: 200php Penalty!');</script>";
            header('Refresh: 0; URL=admin_publicviolation.php');
        }
        else if($offensecount==3)
        {
            mysql_query("insert into tblcitizen(number, price, offenses, fname, lname,'age','gender','violation','officer','date','time') values('$number','1000','4','$fname','$lname','$age','$gender','$violation','$officer','$date','$time')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<script>alert('4th Offense: 1,000php Penalty!');</script>";
            header('Refresh: 0; URL=admin_publicviolation.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('KUKULONG NA PO KAU SORRY PO!');</script>";
            header('Refresh: 0; URL=admin_publicviolation.php');
        }
    }
}
else
{
    header('location:admin_publicviolation.php');
}
?>
```

WHAT IS MY ERROR IN THERE?

Comment: Column identifiers belong into backticks, not single quotes. Also read up on SQL escaping, or parameterised queries if versed.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't wrap column names in quotes. Either use ticks or nothing at all (when allowed):

```
mysql_query("insert into tblcitizen(number, price, offenses, fname, lname, age, 
            gender,'violation','officer','date','time')  
            values('$number','100','2','$fname','$lname','$age','$gender','$violation','$officer','$date','$time')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

should be

```
mysql_query("insert into tblcitizen(number, price, offenses, fname, lname, age, 
            gender,`violation`,`officer`,`date`,`time`) 
            values('$number','100','2','$fname','$lname','$age','$gender','$violation','$officer','$date','$time')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: wait sir, i'll try.

and thank for your help :)

Comment: Make sure you fix it in *all* of your queries.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''`date`,`time`) values('2101094','100','2','Daryl','Coronado','17','male','Resou' at line 1

Comment: I recommend wrapping those column names in ticks because they are reserved words (although date can be left without ticks it is still a good diea).

Comment: I see the error sir :) thank you :) can i add you in your Yahoo Messenger, Skype or facebook for more questions sir? :)

Comment: sir how about i have a table, and i fetch all the data in there, how can i get the latest id to fetch in my table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last question. Do you mean get the latest record in the database?

Comment: i have a table,
 Name, Bank#, Penalty, Cash-in, Cash-out
 Daryl, 123, 5000, 5000, 5000


and if i update that i add another row,

what am i going to do if i want to make bank # not repeat in the table, just 1 row per user

Comment: Make that column a unique key or primary key. That will only allow it to be in the database once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819491/fetch-only-latest-id-or-distinct 

here is my thread

Comment: what am i suppose to do if i want to display the latest bank # only

Comment: Just `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1` in your query

Comment: $news=mysql_query("select *,date_format(time,'%h:%i %p') as timed from tblcitizen");
     
     while($data=mysql_fetch_array($news))
      {
       $number=$data['number'];
       $link=str_replace(" ","-",$number);
       $fname=$data['fname'];
       $lname=$data['lname'];
       $offenses=$data['offenses'];
       $officer=$data['officer'];
       $violation=$data['violation'];
       $date=$data['date'];
       $time=$data['time'];

Comment: print "
        <tr number='X$number'>
        <td width='10px'><center>$lname,$fname</center></td>
        <td width='200px'><center><a href='edit_publicviolation.php?n=$link'><font color='#00FF00'>$number</font></a></center></td>
        <td width='90px'><center>$offenses</center></td>
        <td width='170px'><center>$officer</center></td>
        <td width='230px'><center>$violation</center></td>
        <td width='200px'><center>$date $time</center></td>
        ";
      }
      
        ?>

Comment: You left one of those `'` in there, right before ``date``. That's why he still had an error.